# Is it possible to override a cdef method with def? Override method won't execute

Tags: python, cython

I am implementing a class `MyBinaryTissueClassifier` that has superclass `TissueClassifier` (which I do not have the ability to change). I am attempting to override one of the methods in `TissueClassifier` in `MyBinaryTissueClassifier` but my implementation is not getting called. The superclass function is a `cdef` function and I am using Python and attempting to override with a `def` function. Is this why the code is not overriding?

The `TissueClassifier` class is as follows:

```
cdef class TissueClassifier:
    *code elided*
    cdef TissueClass check_point_c(self, double* point)
        pass
```

`MyBinaryTissueClassifier` class should override it and it looks like this:

```
class MyBinaryTissueClassifier(TissueClassifier):
    *code elided*
    def check_point_c(self, point):
        *method body here*
```

I was expecting the body of the `MyBinaryTissueClassifier` to execute but it is never called, nor is the original instance of `BinaryTissueClassifier`. It seems that the `TissueClassifier` check_point_c() method stops after it calls `pass`.

Answer (score 4):

`cdef` function can be only overriden by a `cdef` (or `cpdef`) function in the derived class. This is also the reason, cython emits warning:

> warning: xxxxx.pyx:yy:z: Overriding cdef method with def method.

for the example above.

The usual `def`-function is very flexible: Not only multiple inheritances must be taken into account, but for example also monkey-patching. But that also means there is not much place for optimization: there is not much more Cython can do than using python's machinery, i.e. [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr)/[`PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GenericGetAttr) + [`PyMethod_GET_SELF`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/method.html#c.PyMethod_GET_SELF) + [`PyMethod_GET_FUNCTION`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/method.html#c.PyMethod_GET_FUNCTION)+ call of the function.

This flexibility leads to large overhead, so  `cdef`-functions avoid it by using a different strategy, which is similar to C++-virtual functions:

- Every `cdef`-class has a virtual table, where the pointer to cdef-functions are stored, every one in its own slot.
- Every object of this `cdef`-class has a pointer to this virtual table thus the calls to cdef-functions can be resolved at the run time and the resolution costs only an indirection.
- A subclass can override a `cdef`-function by putting another function-pointer into the correspoding slot in the virtual table.

A typicall call of the cdef-function looks as follows:

```
%%cython

cdef class A:
    cdef doit(self):
        print(42)
    def call_doit(self):
        self.doit()
```

The `self.doit()` leads to the following c-code:

```
((struct __pyx_vtabstruct_XXX_A*)__pyx_v_self->__pyx_vtab)->doit(__pyx_v_self, 0);
```

The v-table of the object `__pyx_v_self` is interpreted as v-table of the cdef-class `A` (even if `self` is not an instance of `A` but of a derived class, this operation works correctly) and slot `doit` is executed.

When a class, let's say `B` derives from `A` it can override the slot `doit`, so B's version of the `doit` were called. The slot `doit` is overriden by providing a corresponding definition of `cdef`-function.

As one can see, there are different machineries at play when a `def` function is called compared to a `cdef`-function.

Thus `cdef` functions are overriden only by other cdef-functions (and not `def`-functions).  Being more precise, one can also use a `cpdef`-method for overwriting - but in your example it will not work because `cpdef` functions cannot have `double *` arguments, as they cannot be converted automatically by Cython to Python-objects,and the signatures of the overriding and overrided functions must match.